# max_step_size, real_time_factor and real_time_update_rate

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm confused why you can specify all three of them in the world file. As far as I understand they are linearly dependent.

`real_time_factor = max_step_size * real_time_update_rate`

so if i set `real_time_update_rate = 0` (to make gazebo run as fast as possible, what should i set `real_time_factor` to?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/16053/max_step_size,-real_time_factor-and-real_time_update_rate/) by [XaserIII](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3216/xaseriii/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2017-05-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [XaserIII](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3216/xaseriii/) on 2017-05-10**:
anyone? please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I actually crawled the code to check this - real_time_factor is actually not used at all in the code (just set from the .world file and physics message, but never read - at least in the included physics engines, like ODE) and real_time_update_rate determines how long gazebo will sleep between simulation steps if > 0.

---

Originally posted by [XaserIII](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3216/xaseriii/) with karma: 21 on 2017-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe setting `real_time_factor` has no effect. It'll be determined by the other two parameters.

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-05-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SprGrf](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2885/sprgrf/) on 2017-05-16**:
That was my experience as well.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The real_time_factor in simulation will reach max_step_size*real_time_update_rate.
If you want make the simulation run as fast as possible,  set `real_time_update_rate` to `-1`

---

Originally posted by [blevesque](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3192/blevesque/) with karma: 61 on 2017-05-16

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2